# How do i wrap the buttons?

Tags: html, css, layout

[Here is how my code currently renders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArdNp.png), but I want it to [look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KueKx.png)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background: rgb(75, 109, 221);
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
}   
button {
  height: 100px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: large;
}
```

```html
<div className="Home">
  <button class="donate-blood-button">Donate Blood</button>
  <button class="request-blood-button">Request Blood</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using `flex-direction: column`, which basically flips the uses of `justify-content` and `align-items`. Then, set `align-items: center` and `justify-content: space-between` and set a height for the container (I used 300px).

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: rgb(75, 109, 221);
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  height: 300px;
}

button {
  height: 100px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: large;
}
```

```html
<div className="Home">
  <button class="donate-blood-button">Donate Blood</button>
  <button class="request-blood-button">Request Blood</button>
</div>
```

Any time you need help with `display: flex;`, you should test your ideas on [the Yoga Layout Playground](https://yogalayout.com/playground). It's an extremely powerful tool for positioning elements.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.Home
{
   display: inline;
}
```

```css
.Home
{
   display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="Home">
   <button class="donate-blood-button">Donate Blood</button>
   <button class="request-blood-button">Request Blood</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: rgb(75, 109, 221);
  color: black;
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.Home {
  margin:13% 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.Home > button {
  height: 100px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: large;
  margin:50px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="Home">
  <button class="donate-blood-button">Donate Blood</button>
  <button class="request-blood-button">Request Blood</button>
</div>
```